# Moving Button or Any thing else in javafx?

Tags: javafx

```
    Button btn=new Button("Click Me");
    Button btn2=new Button("Click");
    btn2.setOnAction(e->System.exit(0));
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){


        public void handle(ActionEvent action){
            System.out.println(5);
        }
    });
    btn2.relocate(0, 0);
    StackPane root=new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);
    root.getChildren().add(btn2);
    Scene sene=new Scene(root,500,265);
    primaryStage.setScene(sene);
    primaryStage.show();
```

I want to move button and using above code but I am unable to move my button?
What is the problem in code and is their any other way to do it???

Comment: Not sure what excatly you're asking about here. But the answer could be: You're ignoring the fact that `StackPane` is a layout that determines the position of managed children on it's own, i.e. in this case during a layout pulse the children will be centered regardless of previously assigned `layoutX` and `layoutY` (modified by `relocate`). If you want to determine the position of all children yourself, use `Pane`. To just prevent the positioning of selected children, set `managed` to `false` for these children. `StackPane.setAlignment(btn2, Pos.TOP_LEFT)` may work in this case too...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is :

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/animations/jfxpub-animations.htm

JavaFX has ready libraries for animations.

> An example (the rectangle will be faded):

```
final Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 100);
rect1.setArcHeight(20);
rect1.setArcWidth(20);
rect1.setFill(Color.RED);

...

FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(3000), rect1);
ft.setFromValue(1.0); ft.setToValue(0.1);
ft.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
ft.setAutoReverse(true);
ft.play();
```

In your code you maybe need `TranslateTranstition` or just use `translateX` and `translateY` methods